# Css, text shadow - How to get it overflow off the div

Tags: css

I have a div container (header)

```
div.header {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

which contains a h1 named header_title with a text inside:

```
#header_title {
    font: 80px 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -8px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-shadow: 500px 35px 18px white, 300px -50px 30px lightblue;
}
```

Exactly below header div i have my menu, like you see in my image.

If I set a text shadow that will go out the div, (the 4th letter, a 'g') ho can I make it displaying anyway and don't be cut off?

I tried overflow: visible, and z-index solution, but it doesn't work =(

Thanks.

[image]

Markup for header:

```
 <div class=header>
      <h1 id=header_title>Programmazione</h1>
 </div> <!-- fine header -->    

 <div class=menu>
     etc......
```

Comment: Post your HTML markup for header. There should be something with it. See http://jsfiddle.net/mbZkh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `height` property of the `header` and give it a `padding-bottom` of about say 15px for the shadow. That should do the trick.

Comment: or increase the height if you need this property... (though I don't see any reasons for setting it)

Comment: er, you've set the `height` say 215px instead of 115 (which should have shifted your menu 100px down) and still the shadow is cut off?

Comment: Yes. I understood what you though; I thinks I wrote bad what I wanted to say... (Sorry i'm not english =) ) I want to see my shadow OVER the menu =)

Comment: I think we are missing something important from your css file))) Because I've set up a jsfiddle and everything seems to work fine for me using default behavior of block elements. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/kEUBV/

Comment: I put the same code in your webapplication, and there it works O.O... But in my pc no! I use Chrome... In firefox too doesn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10649/discussion-between-tuttoscorre-and-skip405)

Comment: probably you are watching a cached version of the page - try deleting the cache and reload the page... (Ctrl+F5 (or Option+F5 if you are using Mac) may do that in Chrome, if I'm not mistaken) or Shift+F5, try something)))

Answer (score 0):

I don't your HTML markup to test and be sure, but I believe that what is happening is that the the shadow **is** going outside the header div. I see no reason in the CSS you've provided that it wouldn't be.

What is happening is that the menu image that follows is blocking it.  For most browsers, if you are positioning items by default (ie not absolutely, not relatively, not fixed) then, in situations where they overlap, the following neighbor is above.  Also, if you are positioning elements this way, the z-index does **not** affect them.  z-index only works on relative, absolute, and fixed elements.

One solution is to give both elements *position:relative;* and then the position your header div higher than the menu using *z-index*.

Comment: I doubt that they overlap each other... If tuttoscorre were using a negative `margin-top` on the menu (or any other way to shift the element up) he/she would have understood that they overlap) they are definitely static and thus cannot overlap